# Android: Display images in full screen with caption on `onClick` event

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview, picasso

I'm a beginner to the android development. I have an android image view that import web image by using Picasso 2.5.2 library. It's working. After click on that imageview, I want to create a full screen Android dialog with that image. I' used following code for it. But after click on the image view, a dialog is displayed without full screen. Finally, I want to zoom in and zoom out that full screen dialog. I want this kind of full screen on imageview `onClickListener`. Also see how the below image has a title and I also need the image caption (like in Facebook)

[image]

Here is my code

**Mainactivity.java**

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView1;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initUi();
    }

    public void initUi(){
        imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(Uri.parse("http://p.qpic.cn/videoyun/0/2449_43b6f696980311e59ed467f22794e792_1/640"))
                .into(imageView1);
        imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showImage();
            }
        });
    }

    public void showImage() {
        Dialog builder = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Light);
        builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                //nothing;
            }
        });

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(Uri.parse("http://p.qpic.cn/videoyun/0/2449_43b6f696980311e59ed467f22794e792_1/640"))
                .into(imageView);
        builder.addContentView(imageView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_add_info_other"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:text="Image buttons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/image"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You want to popup alert dialog full screen after click on image view.

Comment: Is there any reason to use dialog instead of Activity for FullScreen..?

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran: Actually, no. I am free to use it as well. The thing is it has to be like how WhatsApp or FaceBook display images on click, with the facility to zoom and all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Chrisbane's PhotoView lib](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) for zooming the image.

Open the detail page by sending the path,

```
public void showImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageDeatilActvity.class);

    intent.putExtra("path", "http://p.qpic.cn/videoyun/0/2449_43b6f696980311e59ed467f22794e792_1/640");

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Complete ImageDeatilActvity.java

```
public class ImageDeatilActvity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener {

    private boolean mIsFullScreen;

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_deatil_actvity);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        if (mToolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        }

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        final Drawable upArrow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);

        upArrow.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);

        mIsFullScreen = true;

        String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");

        PhotoView photoView = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.photo_view);

        photoView.setOnPhotoTapListener(new PhotoViewAttacher.OnPhotoTapListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPhotoTap(View view, float x, float y) {
                updateView();
            }

            @Override
            public void onOutsidePhotoTap() {
                updateView();
            }
        });

        Glide.with(this).load(path).into(photoView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
            mIsFullScreen = false;
        }

        updateView();
    }

    public void updateView() {
        mIsFullScreen = !mIsFullScreen;

        if (mIsFullScreen) {
            hideSystemUI();
        } else {
            showSystemUI();
        }
    }

    private void hideSystemUI() {
        mToolbar.animate().translationY(-mToolbar.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
    }

    private void showSystemUI() {
        mToolbar.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
    }

    public int getStatusBarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Detail Activity Layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="in.muthu.stackoverflow.ImageDeatilActvity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#33000000"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>

    <uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/photo_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> In My example, I am using `Glide` not `Picaso`, because Android
>   official recommendation is `Glide`, If you want you can change that.

Answer (score 0):

set image to centre crop and resize it with your screen size like

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(Uri.parse("http://p.qpic.cn/videoyun/0/2449_43b6f696980311e59ed467f22794e792_1/640"))
            .noFade()
            .resize(800, 800)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(imageView);
```

Comment: This is not making it visible in another dialog/activity, with a transparent background on it right? I don't want to make it big in the same place.,

Answer (score 0):

Use below xml for layout, i added one more ImageView just use make the visibility visible on click of small image_view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_add_info_other"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:text="Image buttons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/image"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```